# SQL Group by Year based on after and Before,

Tags: sql-server

I have set of data Name, Id and Joined Date ,want to Group by Year 2019 before joined members and after joined members, need those counts.
I tried below,

```
Select Year(JoinedDate),Count(1) from UserDetails
Group by Year(JoinedDate);
```

It's listed all the year, Please help me to get the solution.
Actual Data:
[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: Added the sample data, Please check @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me you want a conditional sum

```
SELECT CASE WHEN JoinedDate < '20190101' THEN '2019 before' else '2019 after' END AS [Date], 
       count(*) AS [Count]
FROM   UserDetails
GROUP BY CASE WHEN JoinedDate < '20190101' THEN '2019 before' else '2019 after' END
```